# `combineLatest`, `switchMap` and retaining inner subscriptions

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a `Observable<Array<Observable<T>>>` which I want to map to `Observable<Array<T>>`.

When a new array is emitted, the inner observables should unsubscribe/subscribe as follows:

- If `Observable` exists in previous array and the new/current array, *retain* pre-existing subscription
- If `Observable` did not exist in previous array but does exist in new/current array, *create new subscription*
- If `Observable` existed in previous array but does not exist in new/current array, *unsubscribe* from pre-existing subscription

I hoped to achieve this using `switchMap` on the outer observable and then passing `Array<Observable<T>>` into `combineLatest`. However, `switchMap` will unsubscribe from its previous inner `Observable` before subscribing to the new inner `Observable`, which means inner subscriptions are not retained as desired.

Example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-b4wgr1). Given code:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const debugObservable = <T>(t$: Observable<T>, name: string) =>
    new Observable<T>(observer => {
        console.log(name, 'subscribe');
        const subscription = t$.subscribe(observer);
        return () => {
            console.log(name, 'unsubscribe');
            return subscription.unsubscribe();
        };
    });

const ofSingle = <T>(t: T) =>
    new Observable<T>(observer => {
        observer.next(t);
    });

const observableOfArrayOfObservablesOfNumber = new Observable<
    Array<Observable<number>>
>(observe => {
    const keep = debugObservable(ofSingle(1), 'keep');
    const remove = debugObservable(ofSingle(2), 'remove');
    const add = debugObservable(ofSingle(3), 'add');

    observe.next([keep, remove]);

    setTimeout(() => {
        observe.next([keep, add]);
    }, 2000);

    return () => {};
});

// The `switchMap` will unsubscribe to the previous inner observable *before* subscribing to the new
// inner observable.
const final$ = observableOfArrayOfObservablesOfNumber.switchMap(
    arrayOfObservablesOfNumber => {
        const observableOfArrayOfNumbers = Observable.combineLatest(
            arrayOfObservablesOfNumber,
        );
        return debugObservable(
            observableOfArrayOfNumbers,
            'observableOfArrayOfNumbers',
        );
    },
);

final$.subscribe(x => console.log('final', x));
```

This produces:

```
observableOfArrayOfNumbers subscribe
keep subscribe
remove subscribe
final [1, 2]
keep unsubscribe <--- bad!
remove unsubscribe
observableOfArrayOfNumbers unsubscribe
observableOfArrayOfNumbers subscribe
keep subscribe <--- bad!
add subscribe
final [1, 3]
```

However, this is what I desire:

```
observableOfArrayOfNumbers subscribe
keep subscribe
remove subscribe
final [1, 2]
remove unsubscribe
observableOfArrayOfNumbers unsubscribe
observableOfArrayOfNumbers subscribe
add subscribe
final [1, 3]
```

Comment: You could do this with custom operator - something that works like `combineLatest`, but swaps the observables and emitted values like you've described. Are you ok using custom operator or do you insist on combination of existing ones?

Comment: Custom is fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a better solution, to use `combineLatestHigherOrder` from `rxjs-etc`: https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hfze6m?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

I ended up achieving this by publishing + replaying the inner observables with `publishReplay(1)` and then ref counting.

Note that `refCount` is not sufficient because the count will drop to `0` when `switchMap` unsubscribes from the previous inner observable (before it subscribes to the new inner observable), so I had to use a special `refCountWithDelay` operator which only unsubscribes by ref counting after a delay (i.e. within the same tick of the event loop but not synchronously). More on that here:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/171
- https://medium.com/@volkeron/rxjs-unsubscribe-delay-218a9ab2672e
- `refCountWithDelay`: https://gist.github.com/marinho/3637210b13c0f298e1692a0b7b104e64

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4xfwsh?file=index.ts

```
const createObservable = <T>(t: T, name: string) => {
  return refCountWithDelay(debugObservable(ofSingle(t), name).publishReplay(1), 0, 0);
}

const observableOfArrayOfObservablesOfNumber = new Observable<
    Array<Observable<number>>
>(observe => {
    const keep = createObservable(1, 'keep');
    const remove = createObservable(2, 'remove');
    const add = createObservable(3, 'add');

    observe.next([keep, remove]);

    setTimeout(() => {
        observe.next([keep, add]);
    }, 2000);

    return () => {};
});
```

Produces:

```
observableOfArrayOfNumbers subscribe
keep subscribe
remove subscribe
final [1, 2]
observableOfArrayOfNumbers unsubscribe
observableOfArrayOfNumbers subscribe
remove unsubscribe
add subscribe
final [1, 3]
```

Notice that `keep` is only subscribed to once.

Answer (score -1):

The closest to what you described is an xstream operator called [pickCombine](https://github.com/staltz/cycle-onionify/blob/8b6344a749fb5b0ad7c0c8f1dcf2db4e5e1cda03/src/pickCombine.ts) in Cycle.js Onionify.

There doesn't seem to be one single official RxJS operator that solves this, but it is possible to build your own operator that implements this behavior. You can use the xstream implementation of pickCombine as a reference.

Key parts are:

- Stream did not exist in previous but exists in new: https://github.com/staltz/cycle-onionify/blob/8b6344a749fb5b0ad7c0c8f1dcf2db4e5e1cda03/src/pickCombine.ts#L128
- Stream existed in previous but not in new: https://github.com/staltz/cycle-onionify/blob/8b6344a749fb5b0ad7c0c8f1dcf2db4e5e1cda03/src/pickCombine.ts#L107

Notice that it is easier and more efficient to create a [custom data structure](https://github.com/staltz/cycle-onionify/blob/8b6344a749fb5b0ad7c0c8f1dcf2db4e5e1cda03/src/types.ts#L12-L15) (which uses a Map and relies on keys to disambiguate array items) than to do it directly on an array. You can hide the custom data structure from the external API.

Comment: This looks very promising, although I'm a bit stuck on implementing it as an RxJS operator…